# Doctrine DBAL: Updating timestamp field with 'NOW()' value

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex, dbal

Using Doctrine DBAL, I have some code that inserts a new row into the `main` database from a form values binded as `$telephone_international` and `$surname`.

After that is done, it inserts a new record into a duplicate database. `$app['dbs']['backup']`

If that's successful, the entry inserted previously the `main` database gets its `copied` value updated. The `copied` column is a timestamp, default value is 0, but the following code should change it to the current time.

```
$app['dbs']['main']->update('phonebook', array(
    'mediated'  => 'NOW()'
), array(
    'telephone' => $telephone_international, 
    'surname'   => $surname
));
```

But the value is still 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I wonder if `'NOW()'` is being treated as a string.

Comment: as simple workaround you could use php's date functions like: 'mediated'  => time(), to insert a timestamp

Comment: or for DateTime: new \DateTime('now')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i proposed in the comments above, this seems the way to go, as stated here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

So try like this:

```
$app['dbs']['main']->update('phonebook', array(
    'mediated'  => new \DateTime("now")
), array(
    'telephone' => $telephone_international, 
    'surname'   => $surname
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I (for should I say, my co-developer) decided to use `date_default_timezone_set('GMT');` and `'mediated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` to achieve the desired result. I will check to see if this does work in some other app, at which point, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: Now that I've returned to Symfony2 and Doctrine development, I thought I'd revisit this question. The solution would be to use `$now = new \DateTime('NOW', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));`
        then `'mediated' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` to get the current UTC time. I'll acccept this answer since it pointed me in the right direction, but the code in your answer will fail since `DateTime("now")` should be a string, not an object (unless I choose to store it as an object)

Comment: @AdamElsodaney Yes I would have thought the dbal layer would have accepted a `DateTime` object here but I indeed had to format my `DateTime` to `(new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same problem. As there's no much and no good documentation for DBAL itself, I'm going to post my solution.

There's a last parameter which specifies the type (in the order of the data and identifcation array *merged*; as if they were in the same array):

```
$app['dbs']['main']->update('phonebook', array(
    'mediated'  => new DateTime()
), array(
    'telephone' => $telephone_international, 
    'surname'   => $surname
), array(
    'datetime',
    PDO::PARAM_STR,
    PDO::PARAM_STR
));
```